# How can I call a stored procedure within a SQL User Defined Function

Tags: c#, sql

I have created a User Defined function within a SQL Project. This C# Method needs to be able to call a Stored Procedure within the same database. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you mean:  "I have created a User Defined function within a SQL Project. This SQL FUNCTION needs to be able to call a Stored Procedure within the same database. How would I go about doing this?"?

Comment: Yes, the SQL Function is written in C#

Comment: You appear to have answered a different question there and ignored Jim Bs question.  Not sure what you are asking here still?

Are you simply asking how to call a stored procedure from within a sql function?

Comment: Is it a a C# CLR UDF, ie a UDF available on the server but compiled in .NET?

Comment: Hi CodeByMoonlight, yes it is just that. And thanks for all the responses as I have figured out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I've figured it out. What I needed to do is basically access a SQL Stored Procedure within a Managed CLR User Defined Function. And yes it might sound like a poor design issue, but within my application I need to do a quick lookup within my UDF, after a few days of thinking of a way around this (design) there's just no other way. So here is the code of how I done it, the UDF that gets called from within SQL needs to have the following attributes above the method signature:
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read, SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read)]

Within this UDF I then make another call to an internal method called 'GetLookup'. But because GetLookup requires access to the database, the calling method, the UDF in this case needs those attributes to sort out any access issues.

(Variable names etc. aren't the actual ones i've used)

```
private static int GetLookup(int id_Lookup)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Context Connection=true"))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "uspApp_GetLookup";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID_Lookup", ID_Lookup);
                SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("OutputValue", null);
                parameter.DbType = DbType.Int32;
                parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (cmd.Parameters != null && cmd.Parameters["ID_OutputValue_Account"] != null)
                {
                    return int.Parse(cmd.Parameters["OutputValue"].Value.ToString());
                }
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: I honestly had no idea that you could do that - very nice (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131053.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

your  User defined function inside your SQL project is not in c# it is in SQL.
If you have written it in c# then your question doesn't make sense.

If however you want to call a stored proc from c# then you need to look at ado.net
the namespace is System.Data.SQLClient

Comment: It is inside a SQL Project and is written in C#. But it is deployed into SQL as a User Defined and CLR Managed Function.

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that your talking about a [Managed / CLR user defined function](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/04/18/2917.aspx), I don't think you can.

The only way that I can think of that you might be able to is if you create a new connection to the sql server from within your UDF - I can't be sure that this would work, but I am sure that this would be a bad idea - **don't do it!**

I have to ask - why would you want to do this anyway?  CLR UDF's exist for the purpose of using small snippets of managed code (for example regular expressions) in your stored procedures, not processing large result sets (that's one thing that SQL is usually very good at)

Comment: Let's just say that my situation is unique. I figured out how to do it, it's actually pretty cool and since I'm using it to basically do a lookup it's quick too. I wouldn't dare use it with a 'heavy' query so it's not a performance risk in my case. Hope it helps you too if you ever decide to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call a SP in a compiled C# method inside the database, you have to ask yourself if something is wrong with your design. Managed code is not there for remplace Transact-SQL but for complementing the few thinkgs that it can't do by itself.

If you need to call a SP, then your code should be in another SP. Althought is dificult to decide if you don't say more details.

Comment: Hi,
I'm using it for a lookup. My UDF is also utilizing complex Regular Expressions to 'Deciper' a string within a table of mine. Within this string there is a value that I need to query the database on. Have tried this extensively within sq

Comment: ...oops - continued...
within SQL using CROSS APPLY, Custom Function etc. just cannot get it done other ways. At the end of the day the performance exceeded my expectation with no noticable performance degradation when simulating hundreds of thousands of records. So all good :) thanks for the response